# sympy: sympy function symbolic or non-symbolic

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math, isinstance

I am trying to understand about sympy's symbolic functions:

import sympy
from sympy.abc import x,y,z

```
with sympy.evaluate(False):
    print(sympy.sympify("diff(x,x)").func)
    print(sympy.parse_expr("diff(x, x)", local_dict={'diff':sympy.Derivative}).func)
    print(sympy.sympify("Derivative(x,x)").func)
    pass
```

This puts out:

```
Piecewise
<class 'sympy.core.function.Derivative'>
<class 'sympy.core.function.Derivative'>
```

This example should illustrate that `diff` is not a symbolic function yet `Derivative` is.
`sympy.sympify("diff(x,x)").func` results in `Piecewise`.
What exactly makes a function in sympy 'symbolic'?
Why don't both of the functions belong to `<class 'sympy.core.function.Derivative'>`?

I tried to test on a few examples if a function is symbolic using:

```
list_of_funcs = [sin, cos, tan, sec, csc, cot, sinh, cosh, tanh, sech, csch, coth, asin, acos, atan, asec, acsc, acot, asinh, acosh, atanh, asech, acsch, acoth, log, log, log, exp, <class 'sympy.concrete.summations.Sum'>, <class 'sympy.concrete.products.Product'>, Piecewise, jacobi, Piecewise]
with sympy.evaluate(False):
    for f in list_of_funcs:
        if issubclass(f, sympy.Basic):
            print(f'{f}: True')
```

It returned `True` for all yet as far as I understood `Piecewise` is not symbolic.
Could you help me finding a way to test if a function is symbolic?

Comment: It would be easier to follow your question if you showed the results of all those `print` statements.  Without that we have to either "run" the code mentally, or start up a `sympy` session to test them there.  Many of us are either too dumb or too lazy to do that!

Comment: That first `func` is `Piecewise((x, Eq(1, 0)), (1, Eq(1, 1)), (0, True))`.  `diff(x,x, evaluate=False)` does the same as `Derivative(x,x)`.  So somehow the context plus `sympify` forces a different result.  `diff` is a Python function, whose code you can examine.  It isn't a `sympy` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this question without going too deep into coding concepts is not easy, but I can give it a try.

SymPy exposes many functions:

- `cos`, `sin`, `exp`, `Derivative`, `Integral`... we can think of them as symbolic functions. Let's say you provide one or more arguments, then:

  - the function might evaluate to some symbolic numerical value. For example, `cos(0)` will return the symbolic number 1.
  - the function might return an "unevaluated" object. For example, `cos(x)` returns `cos(x)`: this is a symbolic expression of type `cos` (as you have seen by running the `func` attribute). Similarly, you can create a derivative object `Derivative(expr, x)`: this is a symbolic expression that represents a derivative, it doesn't actually compute the derivative!
- Unevaluate functions, for example `Function("f")(x)`, which will render as `f(x)`: this is a symbolic expression of type `f`.
- `diff`, `integrate`, `series`, `limit`, ... : those are ordinary python functions (for example, created with `def diff(...)`) that are going to apply some operation to a symbolic expression. When you call `diff(expr, x)` you are asking SymPy to compute the derivative of `expr` with respect to `x`. What if you wanted to represent the derivative without actually computing it? You write `Derivative(expr, x)`.

So, going back to your example:

```
sympy.parse_expr("diff(x, x)", local_dict={'diff':sympy.Derivative})
```

this can be easily simplified to:

```
sympy.parse_expr("Derivative(x, x)")
```

A few more "relationships":

- `diff` and `Derivative`
- `integrate` and `Integral`
- `limit` and `Limit`

Answer (score 1):

Think of "symbolic" functions as nouns and "non symbolic" as verbs.

```
noun-like        verb-like
----------       ---------
Integral         integrate
Derivative       diff
Sum              summation
Product          product
```

Those that are Python functions (I think what you mean by non-symbolic) emit some evaluated form of something that could also exist in an unevaluated form, e.g. `prod(x, (x, 1, 5)) -> 120; Product(x, (x, 1, 5)) -> no change`.

It would be better to refer to them in some other way. What I think you mean is "evaluated" vs "non-evaluated" (since almost all of SymPy's functions will return SymPy objects with "symbols", even if numeric).

If the `type(thing) -> function` it is not a class itself, it is a Python function. If you check the type of `cos` or `Sum` you will not get `function` as the result.

Whereas some of the evaluates and unevaluated forms may have different names (Sum vs summation) others, like `Add` are evaluative by default but you can use the `evaluate=False` arg to stop that: `Add(x, x) = x + x != Add(x,x,evaluate=False)`. Those which are evaluative can be made non-evaluative by passing `evaluate=True`, e.g. `Derivative(x, x, evaluate=True) -> 1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really like the metaphor! Yet I don't fully understand why sin, cos, etc are 'verbs'. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy-functions-elementary-trigonometric There is a seperate sympy class for them. Will they be used in the unevaluated case and the python function in the evaluated case?

Comment: Almost every function has some basic evaluation that takes place at instantiation - that evaluation is the "verb" character, e.g. `cos(0) -> 1` whereas `cos(0, evaluate=False) -> cos(0)`. There is no "noun" form of `cos` however, only the use of `evaluate=False` in the call keeps it from taking action on certain arguments.